# Scrapy: How to get status of file download

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, please bear with me.

I have a spider that visits a page, and downloads a file. Ultimately I want to write the name of the file, along with other useful information to a db table.

I only want to write the information to the db table if a file is actually downloaded (and not 'uptodate')

--> Right now, I am struggling to find out whether a file has been downloaded or is 'uptodate'.

From the log if a file is downloaded I see:

```
2017-08-22 17:25:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
....,
'downloader/response_count': 5,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 5,
'file_count': 1,
-->'file_status_count/downloaded': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 22, 16, 25, 16, 789000),
'item_scraped_count': 1,
'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'request_depth_max': 1,
....
2017-08-22 17:25:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

If a file has already been downloaded, Scrapy won't download the file again, and it has a log that looks like:

```
2017-08-22 17:32:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
...,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
'file_count': 1,
-->'file_status_count/uptodate': 1,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 22, 16, 32, 49, 787000),
'item_scraped_count': 1,
'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
...
2017-08-22 17:32:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Some how I want to get the status for the download.

I've taken a look at the scrapy code, and I think the function I'm after is 'inc_stats' in the files.py in the pipelines folder:

```
def inc_stats(self, spider, status):
    spider.crawler.stats.inc_value('file_count', spider=spider)
    spider.crawler.stats.inc_value('file_status_count/%s' % status, spider=spider)
```

How do I go about pulling the information I'm after ('downloaded' or 'uptodate') from the actual Scrapy code to my spider?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Currently, to accomplish this you would have to override some code from the ImageDownloader. Maybe a easier way would be to put some logic when creating/updating information on the DB.

Comment: what do you want to do with that `status`? add it to the name of the file? return it as an item?

Comment: @Djunzu I was thinking about checking the folder where items are downloaded to determine whether a new file exists - but thought it must be cleaner to just take the info directly from Scrapy as I can see that it exists.

Comment: @eLRull - I want to populate my db table only with entries when a new file has been downloaded

Comment: in that case you are right, you could use that `inc_stats` method to populate your db when the correct status comes along. You'll have to override your `FilesPipeline`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to override the `FilesPipeline`, and create one on your own to override the `inc_stats` method.

You should have something like this inside your `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    ...
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1
    ...
}
```

Which enables the default `FilesPipeline` that comes with `scrapy`, you can create your own pipeline. Inside a `pipelines.py` (or wherever you want) create a class like this:

```
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class CustomFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def inc_stats(self, spider, status):
        super(CustomFilesPipeline, self).inc_stats(spider=spider, status=status)
        if status == 'downloaded':
            # do whatever you want
```

And to enable that pipeline instead of the one from scrapy, change your `settings.py` to:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    ...
    'myproject.pipelines.CustomFilesPipeline': 1
    ...
}
```

Check that `myproject.pipelines.CustomFilesPipeline` is the path to the pipeline class inside your project.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get information about file download in your spider code, because downloading takes place in the Files Pipeline, hence after processing the item by your spider.

However, you should be able to subclass the standard `FilesPipeline` class and override the [`item_completed`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline.item_completed) method. In that method, you might get some useful information from `results` and `info` parameters and store them in your item before returning. That way, the information would be available to other pipelines ordered after your Files Pipeline. I haven't tested this approach, but I believe it could work.

Comment: This is the way I wanted to go about solving my problem, I accepted @eLRuLL's answer because he went into the detail that I needed to actually make this work.  Thanks Tomas

Comment: @RedBeard Sure, I might have misunderstood your requirement. I thought you actually need to get the status (downloaded, uptodate etc.) per file being downloaded, not just stats.